# string equals or substring search

Tags: c, search, substring

Is there any function in C, that will find string exactly same as string , if there is no exact form, return first string that contains substring?

or i have to use first binary search for exact form, and then linear for substing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `string.h`,

`strcmp(str1,str2);` - returns 0 if strings are same, returns the difference between the strings if they are not same.

`strstr(str1,str2);` - finds whether str2 is a substring of str1.

You may want to use these two library functions and write the required logic.